# How to resolve MongoDB query bracket errors?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

```
db.restaurants.find({ $or: [ { $and: [ {cuisine: {$ne: 'American'}}, {cuisine: {$ne: 'Chinese'}} ] }]}, {name: "/^Wil/"} ] }, {name: 1, cuisine:1})
```

Error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :
```

These kind of long queries have many brackets and I am unable to match them properly. Is there a particular tool/ IDE that we are supposed to use for writing these queries?

Comment: The query has _operators_, _fields_ and _values_. Separate and format them like in a JSON for each operator. Also, use a _code editor_ (instead of a Notepad) - most of them can highlight the opening and closing braces, brackets, etc. Yes, your code has non-matching brackets / braces (I usually use a Programmer Notepad 2 editor for coding/verifying these kind of queries)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.restaurants.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          cuisine: {
            $ne: "American"
          }
        },
        {
          cuisine: {
            $ne: "Chinese"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: /^Wil/
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: 1,
  cuisine: 1
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lWC9y9XVnmx)

For pretty easy queries, use [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net). 
For more complex queries, I usually use `Robo3t / Studio3t`.

Comment: What is the way to type this in the Linux console? Am I supposed to copy paste this there? Will it accept newlines?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Yes. MongoDB shell accepts new lines.